# .Net c# visual studio 2008 error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have the project solution bin in below location for dll, pdb . my build is getting failed due to below error.

```
C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\mysolution\bin\debug\CommonServices.pdb

C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\mysolution\bin\debug\CommonServices.dll
```

**Error**

The command `"C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\mysolution\bin\debug\CommonServices.dll"` exited with code 3.

I tried by cleaning the solution and build / Rebuild. Either way, it is not given result.
Please help.

Comment: Is this a *build* error, or are you trying to *run* the DLL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you have some errors on PropertyGroup.

Read this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/589ffae3-59ca-4d0a-a7b1-9f1120db3792/msb3073-the-command-exited-with-code-3

Comment: I resolved, by deleting a .bat file which is existing under build event tab of VS 2008 in my project.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to consider and try - in the title, it says VS 2008 error, but the path points to 2010, are you sure it is pointing to the right reference for 2008?

If it is, try closing Visual Studio, deleting the pdb file. This will eliminate any pdb issues with building, as the pdb file will be recreated.

Then also delete the .suo file, this will also be recreated. This is to eliminate any build issues that may be caused by Visual studio version conflict.

Another thing to check is if there is any build events in your project that may be triggering this error, go into project properties and remove/edit any build commands.